# Birational morphism $\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ be a birational morphism.

Question: Is $f$ necessarily an isomorphism?

I know that if $f$ is in addition to the assumptions above finite, then it is in fact an isomorphism. This follows from the fact that then $f$ is flat. Now I wonder whether we can drop the assumption on $f$ being finite.